# AVAudioRecorder recording m4a files that are very large

Tags: swift

I'm using AVAudioRecorder and recording m4a files but the files are 14mb for one second. If I were do record an hour the file size would be massive. Is there anyway to reduce the file size?

```
        var recordSettings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatAppleLossless,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0
    ]
```

Answer (score 8):

All I needed to do was change

```
AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatAppleLossless
```

to

```
AVFormatIDKey:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC
```

the file went from 14mb to 856k

Answer (score 0):

```
var recordSettings = [
    AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.min.rawValue,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : 80000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
    AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0
]
```

Comment: the file for 10s, went  ~100k